# How get all elements which match condition in time period in array which contains only from date in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, event-sourcing

I have a collection with items like:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  statusHistory: [
    {
      status: "ACTIVE",
      date: ISODate("2020-04-26T22:02:26.000Z")
    },
    {
      status: "DISABLED",
      date: ISODate("2020-05-20T22:02:26.000Z")
    }
  ]
}

{
  id: 2,
  statusHistory: [
    {
      status: "ACTIVE",
      date: ISODate("2020-05-26T22:02:26.000Z")
    }
  ]
}

{
  id: 3,
  statusHistory: [
    {
      status: "ACTIVE",
      date: ISODate("2020-04-26T22:02:26.000Z")
    },
    {
      status: "DISABLED",
      date: ISODate("2020-04-27T22:02:26.000Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to find all items which had status ACTIVE in May 2020. The array `statusHistory` contains only dates when status was changed. I need somehow aggregate these array to a form where items contain to date too. Something like:

```json
{ 
  status: "ACTIVE",
  date: ISODate("2020-04-26T22:02:26.000Z"), // from
  dateTo: ISODate("2020-05-20T22:02:26.000Z") // it is from the date of the next item in the array
}
```

Then I would like to remove all items out of the period so I want this result:

```json
{
  id: 1,
  statusHistory: [
    {
      status: "ACTIVE",
      date: ISODate("2020-04-26T22:02:26.000Z")
    }
  ]
}

{
  id: 2,
  statusHistory: [
    {
      status: "ACTIVE",
      date: ISODate("2020-05-26T22:02:26.000Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought about to use somehow `$reduce` but I didn't find a solution. It look to me as a common problem in the event sourcing pattern but I am not able to find how to do it.

Comment: You can use `$filter` to select only the array elements which match a condition. In case, you want to include additional information for the selected elements the _also_ use `$map`. Both the operators are used to work arrays in an Aggregation query. You can use `$reduce` (as you say you had tried), but `$filter` is the appropriate operator.

Comment: Can you provide how to do it? Because for filtering I still need the date from the next item in array. I really don't know how to use `$map` and get an the date from the next item. When the elements contains both date from and date to than it is easy to do it but I am need to know how to do it without to date in elements.

Comment: To get the date from the next element in the array, first find the current element's index. Add 1 to that index and you have index to the next element. And, see `arrayElemAt` and `indexOfArray` [Aggergation Array Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pipeline may not be the best but worth giving a try. Will update it with some explanations but to help with understanding the pipeline or to debug it should you get unexpected results, run the aggregation with just the first pipeline step. For example, run the aggregation in mongo shell as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': { .... } }
])
```

Check the result to see if the new `statusHistory` array is constructed properly with a new field `dateTo`. If that gives the expected result, add the next:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': { .... } },
    { '$match': { ... } }
])
```

So overall, run the operation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'statusHistory': {
            '$map': {
               'input': '$statusHistory',
                'in': {
                    '$mergeObjects': [
                        '$$this',
                        { 'dateTo': {
                            '$arrayElemAt': [
                                '$statusHistory',
                                { '$indexOfArray': [
                                    '$statusHistory.status',
                                    'DISABLED'
                                ] }
                            ]
                        } }
                    ]   
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { '$match': {
        '$expr': {
            '$gt': [
                { '$size':  {
                    '$filter': {
                       'input': '$statusHistory',
                        'cond': {
                            '$and': [
                                { '$eq': ['$$this.status', 'ACTIVE'] },
                                { '$gte': ['$$this.dateTo.date', new Date('2020-05-01')] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                } },
                0
            ]
        }
    } },
    { '$addFields': {
        'statusHistory': {
            '$map': {
               'input': {
                   '$filter': {
                       'input': '$statusHistory',
                       'as': 'item',
                       'cond': { '$eq': ['$$item.status', 'ACTIVE'] }
                   }
               },
               'in': {
                    'status': '$$this.status',
                    'date': '$$this.date'
                }
            }
        }
    } },
])
```

Comment: Thanks it helps me I have just update getting index so used:
`{'$add' :[ { '$indexOfArray': [  '$statusHistory.date',  '$$this.date'] }, 1] }`. So I first find the index of the current element by date and then add +1.

Comment: @Saljack Great stuff, glad that helped!